# Confusion regarding the forces in a system of particles

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

I think the internal forces in a system of particles is zero. But is it possible for the sum of internal forces to be non zero in any case?

Answer (score 2):

In non-relativistic mechanics, 3rd Newton's law holds:

Whenever a body is being acted upon by a force due to second body, second body is also being acted upon by the first body, with force of the same magnitude and opposite orientation.

From this law, it can be derived that sum of internal forces in a system is always zero.

In relativistic mechanics, 3rd Newton's law cannot hold, because there is no natural way to select inertial frame of reference, in which the statement could be true (in contrast to non-relativistic mechanics, the forces depend on the choice of inertial frame). Consequently, internal forces do not necessarily cancel each other to zero. A finite-magnitude force may remain unbalanced that will be accompanied by changing momentum of the system, even if no external force is present.

A common case are systems where the forces have magnetic components.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not** possible for sum of internal forces to be zero, as could be concluded from Newton's Third Law that every internal forces will have an equal (in magnitute) opposite force which should also be internal. But beware in your first sentence, it is the **net** vector sum of internal forces which is zero.

Comment: yeah. but is possible for the net vector sum of all internal force to be non zero?

Comment: No, as I was saying it would violate Newton's third law.

Answer (score 0):

**It is impossible for the net vector sum of all the internal forces on the particles of any body or system to be non-zero**. This would violate Newton's third law. Each internal force will have an equal an opposite reaction which is also internal.

Answer (score 0):

In a neutral and stable system of particles, yes the net internal force is zero. But if the particles are charged and non-stable (eg. radioactive particles), then the net force is not zero. The stability of the system of particles can be disrupted by non-uniform electromagnetic field specially if the particles are chemically charged. The particles should also be in thermal equilibrium or else if the system is heated and if the particles are not uniform, the particles vibrate unequally disrupting the stability and hence the net force becomes non-zero.